# After pressing «try or install ubuntu» I only get a black screen

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have a HP pavilion dv6 with Windows 7 installed.
I have ubuntu installed on a Flash drive.
I have tried pressing all options like: try or install ubuntu, OEM-install, Test memory. All I end up with is a black screen with a smal white square blinking in the top left corner.

Comment: Have you checked the USB media works in a different machine?

Comment: HP hardware. I would recommend to set "nomodeset" via the F6 button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)